# How to delete/display a div with JavaSript/jQuery when a condition is met?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to make some customization is my Shopify theme. In my product page `product-template.liquid`, I have a for-loop `{%- for media in product.media -%}`. In this for-loop, I want to add a if-condition, so it is like this:

```
{%- for media in product.media -%}
  {%- if media.alt == "green" -%}
    (rest of the code)
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

However, to be able to change "green" by "red" or "blue" afterward, I want to code this if-condition with JavaScript (e.g. in the `theme.js.liquid`).

For this, I changed the if-condition in the `product-template.liquid` with a div:

```
{%- for media in product.media -%}
  <div data-media-alt-check>
    (rest of the code)
  </div> 
{%- endfor -%}
```

Then, in the `theme.js.liquid`, I added a function:

```js
filterSlidesOnMobile: function(variant) {
      $('[data-media-alt-check]').hide();
        if (variant.featured_image.alt == "green") {
          $('[data-media-alt-check]').show();
        }
 },
```

However, it doesn't behave the same way as when I had the if-condition in my for-loop. It is certainly because of the use of `show()` and `hide()` functions. My question is: do you have better functions to use instead of `show()` and `hide()`? Or maybe you have a better idea instead of adding a `div` in the `product-template.liquid` ?

**EDIT:** The `div` idea was a bad one. So I want to stick with the if-condition as below:

```
{%- for media in product.media -%}
  {%- if media.alt == "green" -%}
    (rest of the code)
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Now my question is: Is there a way to change "green" by "red" or "blue" when a variant is changed in the javascript?

Comment: does hide() work ok? and only show() breaks the layout?

Comment: both hide() and show() work. However, the behavior is different from the first one with just the if-condition `{%- if media.alt == "green" -%}`. Basically, what I want is code this previous if-condition but with JS.

Comment: the problem is div is a block element, also the existing css might adress something with .class>div, conditionwhich you don't meet anymore since you added an extra div element. Also check if the nested elements i(now inside the new div) are using css display:flex;

Comment: Yes indeed the existing CSS of the elements inside my new div isn't working properly. And I checked them and they got the `display:flex;` property.

Comment: so maybe it would be a good idea to update your question with the essential part of the generated html and css?

Comment: Yes, indeed. The problem is the code is within a theme, so there are multiple piece of codes called from different files. But I will edit my question to focus on another point because as you suggested the div idea is a very bad one.

Comment: you could in your if clause add to the relevant elements a class .green. Then with CSS you style the class green as you like. The advantage, once you don't want the green style anymore, just remove the class everywhere